# Adding a fadeOut to tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add a fadeout to the tabs [on my page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/chinese-restaurants/mizu-brentwood-402.html), if someone could help with the javascript side?

Here's the html:

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
        <li class="aboutustab active" style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><div class="up"></div>About</li>
        <li class="maptab"><div class="up"></div>Map</li>
        <li class="featurestab"><div class="up"></div>Features</li>
        <li class="voucherstab"><div class="up"></div>Offers</li>
    </ul>
```

And the here's the javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('.tab:not(.aboutus)').hide();

    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        var thisAd = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(thisAd).children('.tab').hide();
        $(thisAd).children('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab','')).show();
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });


    if(window.location.hash) {
        if (window.location.hash == "#map") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').hide();
            $(".Advert").children('.map').show();
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
            $('.maptab').addClass('active');
        }
        if (window.location.hash == "#voucher") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').hide();
            $(".Advert").children('.vouchers').show();
        }
    }   

});
```

I have the [bootstrap.js plugin](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#transitions) from here and would like to use that, if anyone was familiar with that it'd be ideal.

[Here's how I would like it to work.](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/advertise.html)

Update: This is what I have now, but the fade effect is different for each tab almost - I like the transition back to the About Us tab which isn't as "heavy" as the transition of the others. The offers tab is leaving remnants of the 'Features' tab content too.

```
  $(window).load(function(){

    $('.tab:not(.aboutus)').fadeOut();


    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        var thisAd = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(thisAd).children('.tab').fadeOut();
        $(thisAd).children('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab','')).fadeIn();
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

                newContent.hide();
                currentContent.fadeOut(750, function() {
                    newContent.fadeIn(500);
                    currentContent.removeClass('current-content');
                    newContent.addClass('current-content');
                });

    if(window.location.hash) {
        if (window.location.hash == "#map") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').fadeOut(750);
            $(".Advert").children('.map').fadeIn(500);
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
            $('.maptab').addClass('active');
        }
        if (window.location.hash == "#voucher") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').fadeOut(750);
            $(".Advert").children('.vouchers').fadeIn(500);
        }
    }   

});
```

Comment: Well usually, `.fadeOut()` replaces `.hide()`

Comment: Can you show jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery its very simple... you need not go into that manipulation of code. JQuery UI has tabs widget.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

If you want to load content on Ajax 
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Here is complete API..

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-hide

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KvKJN/)

HTML Changes

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>TAB 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>TAB 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>TAB 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Changed JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut",
            duration: 100
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fadeIn",
            duration: 100
        }
    });
});
```

In your code you can do following changes (assuming contents of all div available at page load time )

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
        <li class="aboutus tab active" style="border-left:1px solid #ccc;"><div class="up"></div><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="map tab"><div class="up"></div><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
        <li class="features tab"><div class="up"></div><a href="#features">Feature</a></li>
        <li class="vouchers tab"><div class="up"></div><a href="#offers">Offers</li>
    </ul>
      <div id="about">
        <p>about TAB 1</p>
      </div>
       <div id="map">
        <p>MAP TAB 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="features">
        <p>features TAB 1</p>
      </div>
     <div id="offers">
        <p>offers TAB 1</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

And java script (remember you need to add jquery and jquery ui js and css)

```
$(window).load(function () {

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        hide: {
            effect: "fadeOut",
            duration: 100
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fadeIn",
            duration: 100
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show jsfiddle.net of your code?  I think the li are actual tab links... and there should be `DIV` elements containing actual AB.. that way.. tab will not hide..

Comment: is your All Tabs  contents are static (Available at load time) or coming from Ajax?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30019/discussion-between-rahul-maindargi-and-ig13)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.tabs li').click(function(){
    var thisAd = $(this).parent().parent();
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('active'); 
    $(thisAd).children('.tab').fadeOut(250, function(){
        $(thisAd).children('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab','')).show();                                                 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

You can change the duration of 250 to whatever you want. All I'm doing is fading out the tab that is currently open before showing the new one in the `fadeOut()` callback.